# Prove by induction that $\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2 = \frac{n(4n^2-1)}{3}, \forall n\in N$

Tags: polynomials, induction

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2 = \frac{n(4n^2-1)}{3}, \forall n\in N$$

First I proved the base case, which is trivial.

Let n=m. Now we need to show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^m (2k-1)^2 = \frac{m(4m^2-1)}{3}, \forall m\in N \implies \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} (2k-1)^2 = \frac{(m+1)[4(m+1)^2-1]}{3}, \forall m\in N$$

So I did this:

$$\sum_{k=1}^m (2k-1)^2 = \frac{m(4m^2-1)}{3} \iff [2(m+1)-1]^2 + \sum_{k=1}^m (2k-1)^2 = [2(m+1)-1]^2 + \frac{m(4m^2-1)}{3} \iff \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} (2k-1)^2 = \frac{3[(2m+1)^2]+m(4m^2-1)}{3}$$

From this point on I spent a lot of time trying to factor the right hand side of the equation to $$\frac{(m+1)[4(m+1)^2-1]}{3}$$ While I was able to eventually get there, it struck me that there must be a much faster way to solve this or some trick to the factorization. I noticed that if I had expanded the original expression right away it would have been much faster, but I was told to not expand expressions as that might lead to too much confusion. In a case like this, what should I do to take less time?

Answer (score 0):

In general, instead of starting the inductive step with

> Now assume the claim is true for the $m^\text{th}$ case for some $m\geq1$, and we will show that it's true for the $(m+1)^\text{th}$ case too.

just offset your indexing like this

> Now assume the claim is true for the $(m-1)^\text{th}$ case for some $m>1$, and we will show that it's true for the $m^\text{th}$ case too.

This makes it so when you are doing the algebraic manipulations in the induction step, the $-1$ will make stuff cancel out, and final thing you are trying to get will look cleaner. In your specific example, it would look like:

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} (2k-1)^2 = \frac{(m-1)\left(4(m-1)^2-1\right)}{3} \\\iff& [2m-1]^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} (2k-1)^2 = \left(2m-1\right)^2 + \frac{(m-1)\left(4(m-1)^2-1\right)}{3} 
\\\iff& \sum_{k=1}^{m} (2k-1)^2 = \frac{3\left((2(m-1)+1)^2\right)+(m-1)(4(m-1)^2-1)}{3}
\\\iff& \sum_{k=1}^{m} (2k-1)^2 = \frac{3\left(4m^2-4m+1\right)+(m-1)(4(m^2-2m+1)-1)}{3}
\\\iff& \sum_{k=1}^{m} (2k-1)^2 = \frac{\left(12m^2-12m+3\right)+(m-1)(4m^2-8m+3)}{3}
\\\iff& \sum_{k=1}^{m} (2k-1)^2 = \frac{12m^2-12m+3+(4m^3-8m^2+3m - 4m^2+8m-3)}{3}
\\\iff& \sum_{k=1}^{m} (2k-1)^2 = \frac{m\left(12m-12+4m^2-8m+3 - 4m+8\right)}{3}
\\\iff& \sum_{k=1}^{m} (2k-1)^2 = \frac{m\left(4m^2\color{red}{+}1\right)}{3}
\end{align}
$$

AHHHHH so close. Probably a baby typo somewhere, but I hope the point is clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to expand at some time.   It is best to do so when most convenient and least confusing.   However, it is a bit of an art.   Although maybe it is somewhat easier to expand than contract.

Which do you prefer, earlier expansions, or all expansion and contraction at the end?

---

For all $n\in\Bbb N^+$ let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2$ and so therefore $S_{n+1}~{= S_n+ (2(n+1)-1)^2\\ =S_n+ (2n+1)^2 \\ = S_n +4n^2+4n+1}$

Assuming $S_n= \tfrac 13 n(4n^2-1)$, we aim to show that $S_{n+1} ~{= \tfrac 13(n+1)(4(n+1)^2-1) \\ = \tfrac 13(4(n+1)^3-n-1)\\ = \tfrac 13(4n^3+12n^2+11n+3)}$

Well, if the assumption is so then, $S_{n+1} ~{= S_n+(2(n+1)-1)^2\\= \tfrac 13 n(4n^2-1)+4n^2+4n+1\\ = \tfrac 13(4n^3+12n^2+11n+3) \\\text{As was to be demonstrated.}}$

---

For all $n\in\Bbb N^+$ let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2$ and so therefore $S_{n+1}~{= S_n+ (2(n+1)-1)^2}$

Assuming $S_n= \tfrac 13 n(4n^2-1)$, we aim to show that $S_{n+1} ~{= \tfrac 13(n+1)(4(n+1)^2-1)}$

Well, if the assumption is so then, $S_{n+1} ~{= S_n+(2(n+1)-1)^2\\= \tfrac 13 n(4n^2-1)+(2n+1)^2\\= \tfrac 13 (4n^3-n)+4n^2+4n+1\\ = \tfrac 13(4n^3+12n^2+11n+3) \\ = \tfrac 13(4(n+1)^3-n-1) \\ = \tfrac 13(n+1)(4(n+1)^2-1) \\\text{As was to be demonstrated.}}$

---

A matter of style really.